# mysql orthogonal table turn

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have the schema like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE prop_set (
      id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name varchar(255),
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );
CREATE TABLE users_props (
      user_id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      prop_id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      value text, 
      PRIMARY KEY (user_id,prop_id)
  );
CREATE TABLE user (
      id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name varchar(255),
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );

INSERT INTO prop_set SET name="prop1";
INSERT INTO prop_set SET name="prop2";
INSERT INTO prop_set SET name="prop3";


INSERT INTO user SET name="user1";
INSERT INTO user SET name="user2";

INSERT INTO users_props set user_id=1,prop_id=1,value="prop1 user1";
INSERT INTO users_props set user_id=1,prop_id=2,value="prop2 user1";
INSERT INTO users_props set user_id=1,prop_id=3,value="prop3 user1";

INSERT INTO users_props set user_id=2,prop_id=1,value="prop1 user2";
INSERT INTO users_props set user_id=2,prop_id=2,value="prop2 user2";
INSERT INTO users_props set user_id=2,prop_id=3,value="prop3 user2";
```

now I run the select  like following:

```
SELECT u.name,ps.name AS prop,up.value
      FROM USER u
        JOIN users_props up ON u.id=up.user_id
        JOIN prop_set ps ON ps.id=up.prop_id;
```

and get output:

```
|  NAME |  PROP |       VALUE |
-------------------------------
| user1 | prop1 | prop1 user1 |
| user2 | prop1 | prop1 user2 |
| user1 | prop2 | prop2 user1 |
| user2 | prop2 | prop2 user2 |
| user1 | prop3 | prop3 user1 |
| user2 | prop3 | prop3 user2 |
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb182/2)
Is there any way to make mysql to return the following output ?

```
| NAME  |   prop1     |     prop2   |    prop3    |
---------------------------------------------------
| user1 | prop1 user1 | prop2 user1 | prop3 user1 |
| user2 | prop1 user2 | prop2 user2 | prop3 user2 |
```

I looking for mysql - only solution.

Comment: The sample data for `prop3` does not match the final desired result - the values are different. Is this a typo?

Comment: typo in query, will fix now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *pivot* syntax of MySQL uses an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement similar to this:

```
SELECT u.name,
  max(case when ps.name = 'prop1' then up.value else null end) Prop1,
  max(case when ps.name = 'prop2' then up.value else null end) Prop2,
  max(case when ps.name = 'prop3' then up.value else null end) Prop3
FROM user u 
JOIN users_props up 
  ON u.id=up.user_id 
JOIN prop_set ps 
  on ps.id=up.prop_id
GROUP BY u.name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb182/4)

The above works great if you have known values to transpose into columns, but if the values are unknown, then you will want to look at using a [prepared statement](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html) to generate dynamic SQL:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when ps.name = ''',
      name,
      ''' then up.value else null end) AS ''',
      name, ''''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  prop_set;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT u.name, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM user u 
                  JOIN users_props up 
                    ON u.id=up.user_id 
                  JOIN prop_set ps 
                    on ps.id=up.prop_id
                  GROUP BY u.name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb182/3)

The result is same with both versions:

```
|  NAME |       PROP1 |       PROP2 |       PROP3 |
---------------------------------------------------
| user1 | prop1 user1 | prop2 user1 | prop3 user1 |
| user2 | prop1 user2 | prop2 user2 | prop3 user2 |
```

Comment: It is possible to not use Prop1, Prop2, Prop3, etc in query ? prop_set can handle 10-20 properties in real app. And the idea is not keep them hardcoded.

Comment: @eicto see my edit showing a dynamic version using prepared statements.